# Is there a way to tell fast-xml-parser how to parse xml tags?

Tags: node.js, fast-xml-parser

I am parsing an XML with [fast-xml-parser](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser). And the result JSON looks like this:

```
{
    RecordingToken: '4dddcdf8-0a0b-42a7-ae6d-231d5d7b6c40',
    Source: {
      Name: 'camera 40',
      Location: 'New Recording - Source Location',
      Description: 'New Recording - Source Description',
      Address: 'http://XXX/onvif/device_service'
    },
    EarliestRecording: '2021-12-02T00:00:00.038235Z',
    LatestRecording: '2021-12-22T08:30:49.364918Z',
    Content: 'Recording',
    Track: [
      {
        TrackToken: '12160e7c-6d41-4eb4-820f-239179b3911a',
        TrackType: 'Video',
        Description: 'Video Track',
        DataFrom: '2021-12-08T00:00:00.036076Z',
        DataTo: '2021-12-22T08:30:49.364918Z'
      }
    ],
    RecordingStatus: 'Recording'
}
```

My issue is that this object is not compliant with [TS naming convention I am using](https://google.github.io/styleguide/tsguide.html#identifiers). All object properties need to have `lowerCamelCase` style.

Is there a way to tell fast-xml-parser that I want to change first letter for xml tags when parsed into JSON? ( RecordingToken -> recordingToken)

Comment: This feature is not currently supported. But if there are many users looking for this feature then probably we can add it.

Answer (score 1):

Fast XML Parser supports [transformTagName](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser/blob/master/docs/v4/2.XMLparseOptions.md#transformtagname) property function from v4.0.9. Using this property, you can transform the tag name in lower case.

```
const options = {
  transformTagName: (tagName) => tagName.toLowerCase()
};
const parser = new XMLParser(options);
const output = parser.parse(xmlDataStr);
```

disclaimer: I'm the author of FXP

Comment: Can I use that with builder, so I can import, process and re-export using the original naming?

Comment: As a follow-up: There's a bug with typings when I try to use the transformTagName in XML Builder options. I'll enter a bug report.

Comment: @raarts it is removed in latest version.